# My script returns the first item only

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-ajax

I'm coding with asp.net/ c# and i'm trying to get the id and the quantity of a product using ajax. The problem is  that my code only recognize the first item otherwise if i tried to enter the quantity of the third product i get an error saying that I haven't provided any quantity.

here's my code :

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.Sendparams').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
//  var  id = $(this).attr('id');
    var quant = $("#quant").val();
var id = $("#id").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/ShoppingCart/AddToCart',
        data:{ "id": id , "quant": quant },
    success: function (response) {
            $("#mainContainerCenter").html(response); } });});
  });
</script>
  <section class="content">
  <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
    <div class="row">    

   @foreach (var album in Model.Produits)
  {


            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                @Html.Hidden("id", album.ProduitId, new { @id = "id" })<br/>

              @album.Nom_Produit<br />
             @album.Categorie.Nom_categorie<br />
               @String.Format("{0:F}", album.Prix)<br />
               @Html.TextBox("quant", null, new { id = "quant" })<br />
                @Html.ActionLink("voila", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = album.ProduitId }, new { @class = "Sendparams" })<br />

            </div> 
    }

     </div>
```

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Comment: what's wrong exactly in my code ??

Comment: You're using the same id in multiple places (`quant`). `$("#quant")` returns only the first element with the id `quant`. Use a class instead.

Comment: I tried the class bu didn't work

Answer (score 0):

`id` attribute would be the uniq value. In your case the `id` is not the uniq, you using the "quant" value for all items (id="quant"). If i correctly understand what you try to do this is code can help: https://jsfiddle.net/9usvg6wv/

```js
$(".item").submit(function( event ) {
  $('#clickedid').text(
   $(this).find('input[name="id"]').val()
  );
  $('#clickedquant').text(
   $(this).find('input[name="quant"]').val()
  );
  console.log($(this).find('input[name="quant"]').val());
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form action="" class="item" >
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
      <input type="text" name="quant" value="100" />
      <input type="submit" class="" >
    </form>
    
    <form action="" class="item" >
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />
      <input type="text" name="quant" value="200" />
      <input type="submit" class="" >
    </form>
    
    <form action="" class="item" >
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="3" />
      <input type="text" name="quant" value="300" />
      <input type="submit" class="" >
    </form>
    
    <form action="" class="item" >
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="4" />
      <input type="text" name="quant" value="400" />
      <input type="submit" class="" >
    </form>
</div> 

<div>
Clicked id:<span id="clickedid"></span>; quant:<span id="clickedquant"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this code but i still get the same problem it only recognize the first item

Comment: try to add calss name to form, example: @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", 
            new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, 
            FormMethod.Post, new { @class="item" }))
{
  etc.
}

and change $(".Sendparams").submit to $(".item").submit

Comment: i made these change but it still wrong i get only the first item

Comment: I never used it but now when i tried it it's not possible to put in it only recognize html